# How can we inject code into a website that has a specific URL in a Chrome extension with Manifest 3?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, code-injection

I have a website with a specific url and we're creating an extensión that should inject a snippet in the head section (a style and a script)

However, it is not working and Google information is not helping at all.

This is the manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Alert Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "scripting"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

And this is the content of the background.js:

```
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(function(details) {
  if (details.url.includes('domain.subdomain.com')) {
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: { tabId: details.tabId },
      code: `
        if (!document.getElementById("myStyle")) {
          var style = document.createElement("style");
          style.id = "myStyle";
          style.textContent = "/* CSS content goes here */";
          document.head.appendChild(style);
        }

        if (!document.getElementById("myScript")) {
          var script = document.createElement("script");
          script.id = "myScript";
          script.textContent = "/* Javascript content goes here */";
          document.head.appendChild(script);
        }
      `
    });
  }
});
```

I would like also to check if that code has not been added yet as I woulnd't like to be injecting the code twice or even more.

Does anybody know how to overcome this issue?

I tried to apply different solutions:

Solution 1:
manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Alert",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "scripting"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://subdomain.domain.com/*"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

injected.js:

```
    var code = "\/\/Etiqueta de script"; // Code to be injected in the head section
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    var nonce = 'myrandomnonce';

    script.setAttribute('nonce', nonce);
    script.appendChild(document.createTextNode(code));
    document.head.appendChild(script);
```

content.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.action === 'injectCode') {
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: { tabId: sender.tab.id },
      files: ['injected.js']
    });
  }
});
```

background.js:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (changeInfo.status === 'complete' && tab.active) {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true, url: '*://subdomain.domain.com/*' }, function(tabs) {
      if (tabs.length > 0) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, { action: 'injectCode' });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

SOLUTION 2:
manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Alert",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "scripting",
    "webNavigation"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  }
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(function(details) {
  if (details.frameId === 0) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(details.tabId, { file: "injected.js" });
  }
});
```

injected.js:

```
alert('We are in the website');
```

SOLUTION 3:
manifest.js:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "test Alert",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "scripting"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://subdomain.domain.com/*"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

content.js:

```
function injectCode() {
  var code = "\/\/Etiqueta de script";
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.appendChild(document.createTextNode(code));
  document.documentElement.appendChild(script);
}

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (changeInfo.status === 'complete' && tab.active) {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true, url: '*://subdomain.domain.com/*' }, function(tabs) {
      if (tabs.length > 0) {
        chrome.scripting.executeScript({
          target: { tabId: tabId },
          function: injectCode
        });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Solution 1 throws this error:
"Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval' 'inline-speculation-rules' http://localhost:* [http://127.0.0.1:*"](http://127.0.0.1:*%22). Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-tjq+f9k3DXjCYpN8P19vmoR+gGAU/7ojD5Y2lMnE774='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution."

Solution 2 throws this error:
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval' 'inline-speculation-rules' http://localhost:* [http://127.0.0.1:*"](http://127.0.0.1:*%22). Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-tjq+f9k3DXjCYpN8P19vmoR+gGAU/7ojD5Y2lMnE774='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Solution 3 throws this error:
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval' 'inline-speculation-rules' http://localhost:* [http://127.0.0.1:*"](http://127.0.0.1:*%22). Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-tjq+f9k3DXjCYpN8P19vmoR+gGAU/7ojD5Y2lMnE774='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Answer (score -1):

I already resolved this.

I've added this code to the background.js:

```
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
      if (changeInfo.status === 'complete' && tab.url.includes('domain.subdomain.com')) {
        chrome.scripting.executeScript({
          target: { tabId: tabId },
          function: () => {
            if (!document.getElementById("myStyle")) {
              var style = document.createElement("style");
              style.id = "myStyle";
    
              style.textContent = `/* CSS Style goes here */`;
    
              document.head.appendChild(style);
            }
    
            if (!document.getElementById("myScript")) {
              var script = document.createElement("script");
              script.id = "myScript";
    
              script.textContent = "alert(\"This works\")";
              document.head.appendChild(script);
            }
          }
        });
      }
    });
```

The content of manifest.json was changed to this:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Injector Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "host_permissions": [
    "https://domain.subdomain.com/*"
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "scripting",
    "tabs"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

Hope this helps to others :)

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**